# Ubuntu 22.04 won't shut down, or reboot, and WIFI won't work, after wake from suspend

Tags: suspend, shutdown

every time when the laptop goes to sleep, and I wake it up, the WiFi is down, and it can't be turned on. Reboot or shutdown causes a infinity loop to wait forever saying "A stop job is running (..)"
INFO: task NetworkManager:537 blocked for more than 241 seconds.
INFO: task cups-browsed:724 blocked form more than 241 seconds.
INFO: task lxd:3974 blocked for more than 241 seconds.
And so on.
Any way to fix the suspend problem?

Comment: Use a LiveUSB's "Try Ubuntu" environment to test a newer release of Ubuntu without touching your existing install.. The bug might be fixed in a newer release.

Comment: any hel;p in [this answer](https://letsfoss.com/fix-wifi-not-working-after-suspend-in-ubuntu/)?

Comment: I have tried the newest Ubuntu version, but the problem still persists.

Comment: Graham, that answer did not help, i tried manualny the command "service network-manager restart" end it gives Failed. Unit network-manager.service not found.